# SSH access using .pub key

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh

I don't know if I'm overthinking this too much but I can't seem to understand how to use a ssh public key to create an ssh connection trough my mac.

I'll list my steps bellow:

1. First created the SSH keys in my server in cpanel -> SSH keys and created a key pair with name `id_rsatest`
2. Then I downloaded to my mac both public and private key files, so now in my downloads folder I have the files: `id_rsatest` and `id_rsatest.pub`
3. Then I moved the `id_rsatest.pub` file to `Users/myuser/.ssh/` and opened Terminal.app -> Shell -> New Remote Connection and entered the information below:

   [image]

   and receive this error:

   ```
   ssh: connect to host example.com port 22: Operation timed out
   [Process completed]
   ```

What am I doing wrong? Is this even the way on how to create a SSH access with SSH keys?

Comment: `Operation timed out` sounds like network problem. Can you ping the host?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got it the wrong way round :-)

- create a key pair on the Mac you are using
- put both `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa` into `~/.ssh` and run `chmod 600 id_rsa`
- append the generated public key (`id_rsa.pub`) to `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote machine (your server in this case). If you are allowed to login in via `ssh` using a password, use

  ```
  ssh remoteuser@remotemachine "mkdir ~/.ssh; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys" < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  ```

  otherwise transfer the file by whatever means you have to upload files.
- run `ssh remoteuser@remotemachine` in your shell to connect

PS: **The private key should never need to leave the machine it's generated on**